# Are Alanna of Trebond and George Cooper legally siblings?

Tags: tamora-pierce, tortall-universe

While re-reading the Song of the Lioness quartet, I came to a disturbing realization: Alanna and George are technically siblings. George is the son of Eleni Cooper, and Alanna is the adoptive daughter of Sir Myles of Olau. Eleni Cooper and Sir Myles marry. In-universe, does that make Alanna and George legally siblings, and if so, is that fact ever addressed or commented on in canon or by the author?

Comment: I'm sending a message to Ms. Pierce. I will let you know if she responds.

Comment: Not to mention that George is his **step**-son.

Answer (score 2):

A cursory reading would suggest that while Myles is George's step-father, George isn't ever made Myles' legal heir. He's just the adult son of his new wife.

George does briefly consider the implications of their changed relationship, but only in a humourous context.

> Myles held Eleni’s hand a moment too long, making George think. This possibility hadn’t occurred to him before. A fine thing, to be **gettin’ a new Pa at my age**, he thought with a grin.
>
> <sub><sup>Lioness Rampant</sup></sub>

By comparison, Alanna is Myle's legal heir and daughter.

> Now she could only brace herself as Halef Seif lightly cut Myles’s wrist, then hers, pressing them together as blood welled out. Once again Alanna felt odd joining-magic as Halef Seif commanded, “Become one with each other, with the Bazhir, with the desert we love.” The combined drops fell, soaking into the sand as the tribesmen cheered.
>   “Now, was that so bad?” Myles asked her as Farda bandaged them both. **Alanna grimaced and watched the witnesses sign the legal documents Myles had brought with him from Corus.** Then she realized she now had a father who loved her, and she laughed as tears ran down her face.
>
> <sub><sup>The Woman Who Rides Like a Man</sup></sub>

There appears to be no good in-universe reason why the relationship status of two unrelated adults would be changed/barred by the marriage of their parents, as there wouldn't be in Boston, where the author lives.

Comment: So they are step siblings?

Comment: @DanielB - It's not really clear what their legal status would be. In the Bazhir tradition, an adoption appears to be a legal but also mystical bond. Myles certainly doesn't share that with George. In our world they would be considered step-siblings by marriage and adoption.